# Gem Seer and Ajax on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, partial

I am trying to display a Line graph using [Seer](http://rubygems.org/gems/seer) using Ajax.

But all I get is a blank page when I make an ajax request.The same partial works fine when I display is using a `render :partial`.

Here is the partial _show.html.erb

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<%= Seer::init_visualization -%>
<%= Seer::visualize(
      sensors, 
      :as => :line_chart,
      :in_element => 'chart',
      :series => {
        :series_label => 'location',
        :data_label => 'id',
        :data_method => 'value',
        :data_series => series
      },
      :chart_options => { 
        :height => 250,
        :width => 500,
        :axis_font_size => 12,
        :colors => ['#0099CC','#990000','#009900'],
        :title => "Rain Data",
        :point_size => 0,
        :line_size => 3,
        :title_y => "Water Level in Feet",
        :smooth_line => "true",
      }
     )
 -%>
```

This works:

```
<%= render :partial => 'hcfcdsensors/show', :locals => {:sensors => @sensors , :series => @series} %>
```

But this Doesn't:

```
<%= link_to_remote "show" , :url => show_graph_hcfcd_url(@hcfcdsensors) ,:update => "graphDiv" %>
```

The complete web page just goes blank.
I have checked the action and availability of required variables in the page and its all there fine.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks
Shaunak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making ajax call, You need to draw the chart manually.
Seer user " drawChart()" method to draw the chart.

Below is my ajax response

```
<% result_script = Seer::visualize(
      @flight_result_search.sell_classes_for_graph, 
      :as => :area_chart,
      :in_element => 'historical_sellout_chart',
      :series => {
        :series_label => 'name',
        :data_label => 'days_prior',
        :data_method => 'capacity',
        :data_series => [@flight_result_search.current_sell_for_graph,@flight_result_search.historical_sell_for_graph]
      },
      :chart_options => { 
        :height => 400,
        :width => 600,
        :axis_font_size => 11,
        :title => "Historical Sell Out Chart",
        :point_size => 3,
        :color =>['#324F69','#90000B']
      }
     )

%>
<%= result_script.gsub("</script>",' drawChart();</script>') %>
```

Don't forget to eval your ajax response as it is javascript code .
Also drawChart() should be in same script tag otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, This worked on my quick try, and i could see the graph when i used the ajax link in browser. But now wheni have actually put it in the rails application, it still goes blank, only error this time is "Container is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

Couple of questions... what happens if you move <%= Seer::init_visualization -%> to the enclosing page rather than the partial? Also, check to see if there are any JavaScript errors when you refresh the page. In Safari or Firefox, open up the Console to check.

Comment: I get the same result when I move the <%= Seer::init_visualization -%> to the enclosing page. I am using chrome, and console tool on chrome. There is not error on the page initially. When I click the link that makes and ajax request, I just get an blank page.

Comment: I cleaned up things, and put this on a clean page just to check. I still have the same problem. This time i get an error: '[16:34:30.093] google is not defined /javascripts/prototype.js?1300914093:403' in firefox.

Comment: but at the same time, if i try the link ajax uses separately i can see the graph no issues.

Comment: I am still stuck with this :(.. any clues??